# Hiding one canvas makes another canvas unselectable

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In Fabric.js, if there are two canvases and one is hidden using jQuery, then the remaining canvas becomes uneditable. Why is that the case? Is there a solution to this problem? Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVE33/6/) of the problem.

Html

```
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
<hr/>
<canvas id="c2" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
<button id="hide">hide the top canvas</button>
```

CSS

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2');
canvas.add(new fabric.Text('hello', {left: 50, top: 40}));
canvas2.add(new fabric.Text('hi', {left: 20}));
$('#hide').click(function() {
    $('#c').parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `canvas.calcOffset();` on your visible canvas after you hide the other canvas.

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pVE33/7/